# useNativeDriver true for custom native components

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

We found that going over the RN Bridge with frequent events is a no-go for older devices like the iPad 2 or iPad Mini. For example sending the video progress every x ms for a video component will make a RN app unresponsive on old devices.

We are currently trying to use the NativeDriver support to fill that gap and animate the progress without going over the bridge but it is quite frustrating as we can not find any docs or information about the requirements on the native (ios) part to make the following syntax working on custom native component:

```
<Video
   onProgress={Animated.event([{ currentTime: animatedProgress }], { useNativeDriver: true })}
/>
```

Any ideas appreciated!